Is it Possible to Generate Articles Based on Structured Data
Experienced software engineer, but real noob with Gen AI, so forgive the question if too basic.
Data Available
We have structured (tables in Big Query and some in PostGres) market tick data and transaction volumes of some stocks, Cryptos and other assets.
Goal
Automatically generate some articles(~5000 words) based on the structured data tables (reflecting up to years of data, until yesterday) and the user prompts. Examples of some user prompts may be

Write an article on Apple price movement for last year
Write an article on technology stocks for last month
Write an article on ETH with the latest market data

Question
So is LlamaIndex coupled with Ollama a suitable framework for achieving this? What kind of connectors will be suitable to Vectorise the structured SQL-like Database schemas/tables (into a RAG) and making sure that the model can generate articles?
In particular, just a high level overview of tools/components necessary would be great (preferably using Open source, but optionally can subscribe to OpenAI as well), so that I can do further research.

Generating Articles (~5000 Words) from Structured Market Data Using LlamaIndex and Ollama
Question Context:
You have structured market data (e.g., tables in BigQuery and PostgreSQL with tick data and transaction volumes for stocks, cryptos, etc.) and want to generate detailed articles (~5000 words) based on user prompts. Prompts might include:
Write an article on Apple price movement for last year.
Write an article on technology stocks for last month.
Write an article on ETH with the latest market data.
You're exploring whether LlamaIndex combined with Ollama is a suitable framework for this use case and what tools/components might be required. Here's a high-level overview.
Suggested Architecture

Data Processing and Vectorization
SQL Connectors:
Use LlamaIndex’s native connectors for BigQuery and PostgreSQL. These allow direct querying and transformation of structured data into a textual format that can be indexed. For example:
Extract yearly price movement summaries.
Aggregate transaction volumes or other key metrics.
Embedding Models:
Choose an embedding model to convert textual summaries or schema metadata into dense vector representations. Options include:
sentence-transformers
OpenAI embeddings (if using GPT APIs).
Building a RAG Pipeline
Indexing:
Use LlamaIndex to create vector indices. Organize the data into segments (e.g., time periods, asset classes) to make retrieval more efficient and contextually relevant.
Retrieval:
Enable a query-based retrieval mechanism to fetch relevant vectorized data for a given user prompt. This ensures that only relevant sections of the database are passed to the LLM for processing.
Generative Model for Article Creation
Choosing a Model:
Ollama is a great choice if you’re looking for an open-source, locally hosted solution. It supports models like LLaMA 2. If you’re open to subscriptions, OpenAI’s GPT-4 offers state-of-the-art capabilities out of the box.
Integration:
Use the retrieved data as context for the LLM. Craft prompts that combine user input (e.g., Write an article on...) with retrieved database insights to ensure the model generates coherent and relevant output.
Workflow and Orchestration
Prompt Engineering:
Dynamically generate prompts that combine user requests and the retrieved data. For instance, structure the prompt to include both the user's query and key data summaries.
Data Validation:
Ensure freshness by syncing data nightly or in real-time. Verify that the latest available data (up to yesterday) is included in the pipeline.
Article Structuring:
Predefine article templates to ensure a logical flow (e.g., introduction, analysis, conclusion). This helps maintain consistency across generated articles.
Recommended Open-Source Components
Here’s a breakdown of the tools you can use:

Data Management:
LlamaIndex: Connect to databases, create vector indices, and retrieve context-relevant information.
LangChain: Complements LlamaIndex by offering pipelines for prompt management and chaining.
LLM Hosting:
Ollama: Locally host LLaMA-based models.
Hugging Face: Access and fine-tune open-source LLMs.
Embeddings:
sentence-transformers: Convert structured data into embeddings for indexing.
OpenAI Embeddings (optional).
Interface and Visualization:
Gradio or Streamlit: Create an interactive UI for users to input prompts and view generated articles.
